# Get a 0KB file after using PHP unlink() method

Tags: php, delete-file

I'm trying to delete a file on the server. Below is the code I use.

```
function ServerDel($file){
        $file = realpath($file);
        echo ($file);
        $fh = fopen($file, 'w') or die("can't open file");
        fclose($fh);
        if(unlink($file))
            echo"Delete the file successfully.";
        else
            echo "Failed to delete.";
}
```

But after I run the code, the file still exists and becomes 0KB. Anyone knows how to get around this?

Comment: Why are you opening the file just to delete it? Are you looking for the [`file_exists`](http://php.net/file_exists) function?

Comment: Also, do you get the `successfully` or `failed` message? Is error reporting active, does it show any warning?

Comment: It's to check if the file is opened by other apps. I now get error "Failed to delete".

Answer (score 1):

<strike>use `a` flag in `fopen()` instead of `w`.</strike>

```
$fh = fopen($file, 'a') or die("can't open file");
```

Try this:

```
function ServerDel($file){
        $rfile = realpath($file);
        echo ($rfile);
        if (file_exists($rfile)) {
            if(unlink($rfile)) {
                echo "Delete the file successfully.";
            } else {
                echo "Failed to delete.";
            }
        } else {
            echo "File does not exist";
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I changed the flag and now I get "Failed to delete." msg.

Comment: I'm running on Windows 2003, if that matters. What is the tag for?

Comment: actually, the `w` flag truncates the file to zero length. I'm editing my answer.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. I tried the new code but still get failed to delete error..

Comment: can you please show me how you are using your `ServerDel` function?

Comment: I had a switch loop. when detecting the file is stored on server, i call the ServerDel function. The echoed value of $rfile is sth. like c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\temp\File Name.PDF

Comment: How are you running the script? Through command line? Maybe because you don't have permissions.

Comment: It's a web app, running from IE. I gave full permissions to everyone.

Comment: I just tried again and it works!! Maybe there was some caching. Thanks a lot for your help, Ruel.