# How to delete a client side file using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, delete-file

I have a PHP app and I need to delete a client-side file. How can I achieve that?

I'm new to PHP. Hope someone can help me.

Comment: A browser being able to delete a client-side file at the control of a website, no matter what language the website uses behind the scenes, is definitely a security problem and browser bug. In short: you can't. And if you figure out some way, report it to the browser makers so they can fix it.

Comment: Have you really thought this through? Imagine if any website could simply delete files on your hard disk... Holy Security Nightmare, Batman!

Comment: ok... thanks for all your responses

Comment: Just curious, what was your requirement to do such a "heinous" act?

Comment: @zengr That made me LOL.

Comment: It's a requirement from customer. I may need to discuss with him. It seems more people are looking at this post. Do you happen to be able to help me with another question? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011727/get-a-0kb-file-after-using-php-unlink-method

Answer (score 9):

You can't, browsers won't allow it, full stop.

<sub>You *could* if you wrote a browser/ActiveX/Java plugin that has that kind of access and got the user to install it, but **please *don't***.</sub>

Comment: +1, but I think that smaller paragraph should actually be bolder :)

Comment: @alex No, it actually shouldn't be there at all. You **can't** delete client-side files, full stop. :o)

Comment: Well, I meant the `please don't` part :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this for obvious security reasons. PHP is server side only.