# Are these snippets possible with HTML and/or javascript

Tags: javascript, html, batch-file

Question:

We have a situation at work where we would like to run the following scripts:

```
xcopy /s c:\STANDAARD_DETAILS_V2\PDF\8.1A.pdf C:\STANDAARD_DETAILS_V2\TEMPDUMP


del /s "C:\STANDAARD_DETAILS_V2\TEMPDUMP\*.pdf"
```

However the I.T. manager is dead against batch scripts is there a html or javascrip code/ equivelent for doing this.

Note the IT manager is not against the function of the script, its simply a no batch files policy.

Comment: No batch files? How does anything get done?

Comment: Oh, you wouldn’t want that such commands can be triggered from a web page.

Comment: Oh he can run batch, we not permited makeing or running our own,

Comment: second person can and want are two diffrent things ive see and collected some crazzy html in the last few years

Comment: I'd start brushing up my resumé, this policy seems too crazy...

Comment: the codes would be in html format but only avalable within the companys network "safe environment"

Comment: its a good job, just a self made I.T. manager with lack of understanding

Comment: I was about to write an answer, but it's actually easier to link to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011792/how-to-delete-a-client-side-file-using-php/4011803#4011803), which is exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

No. You cannot run these commands using javascript or html, that would be a function they're absolutely not considered for. Simplest would be a batch script... 
If your IT Manager just doesn't like batch scripts, there are several ways:

- Install some script language
  interpreter on the machine and write
  a script in another language (e.G. Python, Perl, Ruby, ..)
- Write several lines that call exec() in C or C++ or whatever else language you can compile to a .exe file, and give him the .exe file
- Write a batch script and change the file extension from .bat to .cmd

Comment: same policy on .exe (he's got a problem now hes hierd an Autocad admin guy who likes stepping out of the normal boundrys)

Comment: @Bob Seriously, what *are* you allowed to do there? :)

Comment: the .cmd others are going to requer me to learn entier languages and programs for simple things like this (havent the time ....today, lol)

Comment: write Auto lisp they employed me to keep Autocad in shipshape only that was too boring.

Comment: tryed the .cmd what im trying to do is have it run from a linked file within Acrobat, all it keeps returning is that Acrobat wont allow it. see system administrator.

Comment: @Bob honestly, what do you want? You cannot use .bat files, but you don't want to use another language? Then just forget it... The only thing that comes to my mind now is just creating a windows .lnk file (Right click->create shortcut/link) and give ` xcopy /s c:\STANDAARD_DETAILS_V2\PDF\8.1A.pdf C:\STANDAARD_DETAILS_V2\TEMPDUMP;del /s "C:\STANDAARD_DETAILS_V2\TEMPDUMP\*.pdf ` as "Run command", but I don't know if windows is intelligent enough to run several commands when they're seperated by ";"

Answer (score 0):

You could always do it through PHP (that is, if he turns a blind eye to using web scripts), but that's basically abstracting it another level for no reason. Or make JavaScript call a CGI binary which does it. For reference the PHP code would basically be

```
<?php
exec("xcopy /s c:\STANDAARD_DETAILS_V2\PDF\8.1A.pdf C:\STANDAARD_DETAILS_V2\TEMPDUMP");
exec("del /s \"C:\STANDAARD_DETAILS_V2\TEMPDUMP\*.pdf\"");
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Then he must install XAMPP or at least just php, and XAMPP as far as I know contains many exes and .bats :P

Comment: I suppose so yeah. I'm assuming that they've got some form of web server running though.

Comment: php,never used it remember im self taught, perhaps you could sugest a website outling its usage. also hens the request of a html or javascript equivlent as i also thought of ussing them as a "brige" to launch the .bat, only then you run itno that blasted activ x warning and a stuipid autoshat brouwser remains open (now requiers too many clicks for simple minded end user)..

Comment: checked the active x state and this can not be fiddeld with either as hes put a bar on this too, yikes what a control freak!

Comment: Like joni suggested, you'll probably need to have XAMPP installed and running or IIS on your local machine with PHP support enabled. Sounds like PHP isn't the answer, sorry.